# Use remove event listener for oop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dom-events

I have a button that updates content using Firebase realtime database. I use one button to update each of my content. So my first update works correctly, but when I want to update through the second content, it updates with my previous content. I want to remove the event after each update. This way, the update for each content will work correctly. Can you help me figure out how to do this?

This is what my update button does. After updating, I want to remove the click event until it is clicked again.

```
  addUpdatedTodoToFirebase(todoKey) {
  console.log(todoKey) // key used for each todo
  if (todoKey) {
    this.updateTodo.addEventListener("click", () => {
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${this.currentUser}`).child("todos").child(todoKey).update({
        action: this.selectAction.value,
        date: this.selectDate.value,
        title: this.inputTitle.value,
        description: this.inputDescription.value
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an event listener from the DOM, you can do so with:

```
let listener = () => {
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${this.currentUser}`).child("todos").child(todoKey).update({
    action: this.selectAction.value,
    date: this.selectDate.value,
    title: this.inputTitle.value,
    description: this.inputDescription.value
  }).then(() => {
    this.updateTodo.removeEventListener("click", listener);
  });
})
this.updateTodo.addEventListener("click", listener);
```

The above code removes the listener once the update of the database completes.

Comment: Thank you so much, Frank! I knew you'd see :) you're definitely our saviour on Firebase!